# -ly adverb at the beginning of the sentence

Tags: syntactic-analysis, sentence-starts, disjuncts

I once took a multiple choice exam where there was a section with all possible answers being made up of a single word, an -ly suffix adverb followed by a comma at the beginning of the sentence. According to my own judgement, I answered correctly, but for some reason I failed that portion.

What do you call this type of sentence? Are there in-depth resources about this topic so that I won't fail again when faced with the same problem?

Comment: Please [edit] this to quote an example for the exam for us. I'm having a hard time picturing what you're describing.

Comment: Frankly, I do not know what they are called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sentences like these use [disjuncts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunct_%28linguistics%29)

> A specific type of disjunct is the sentence adverb (or sentence adverbial), which modifies a sentence, or a clause within a sentence, to convey the mood, attitude or sentiments of the speaker, rather than an adverb modifying a verb, an adjective or another adverb within a sentence.
>
> Here are some examples (note: the disjuncts that follow are 'sentence adverbs'):
>
> - Honestly, I didn't do it. (Meaning "I'm honest when I say I didn't do it" rather than "I didn't do it in an honest way.")
> - Fortunately for you, I have it right here.
> - In my opinion, the green one is better.
> - Frankly, this whole paragraph needs work.

Source- wikipedia

Comment: Quickly scarfing down his hamburger, Frank ran for the train.

Comment: Although @HotLicks’ example does not counter this particular case (the asker specifically says that a comma follows the _-ly_ word), the point is valid: position and comma alone is not enough to judge whether you’re dealing with a sentential adverbial or not (as the Wikipedia article also points out). “Finally, he nodded” is disjunctive; “Quietly, he nodded” is purely adverbial, describing the act of nodding, rather than the sentence as a whole.

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction I still don't understand how I could make a mistake in an adverbial adjuncts. My answers sounds right during those exams, but I found that I didn't got a good result on that portion. Are there specific rules to determine if a disjunct is correct or not?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: You're both right. `-ly,` isn't always a sentence adverbial, but it could very well be. Disjuncts are tricky, maybe that's why the OP failed. Just trying to point that out. If you wish, you can edit my answer to make your point.

Comment: @Corbee You’ll have to tell us _what_ the mistake was, otherwise we have no way of helping you find out how you could make the mistake.

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction they just give multiple choices all ending in -ly, followed by a comma then the sentence. I picked what sounds right. They didn't explain why it's incorrect. Let me try if I could retrieve the results.